# Rest: API structure to connect two users on the website?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

Consider it to be simple version of tinder with NO LOGIN where every user has is identified by mobile number. Once user submits his/her mobile number, he/she gets back unique customerId. We want to create API that would let users view each other's contact information. To see other users information, you need to share your information to the other user too. Following API structures are possible:

1. GET /api/user/{userId}/?mobile={mobile} : The query string information {mobile} is mobile of the viewer and {userId} is id of the customer to which viewer is showing interest towards. This API will return user details of {userId} and save this transaction in a lead table (userId, mobile, user2) & creates user2 with {mobile} passed in case it's already not registered. Problem here is that we are doing database update in get request which is not correct.
2. POST /api/lead/: Here we send {userId},{mobile} in POST body and this sends back details of {userId} in response. But this does not look like rest convention where POST creates a resource and send back that resource in the response.
3. Create one POST API to save this lead transaction and separate GET API to fetch user details. Problem here is two APIs which would be called sequentially?

What is the most restful approach here?

Comment: Presumably your users are authenticated? Why do they need to specify information you already have about them?

Comment: no they are not authenticated.

Comment: How do you prevent people from editing other people's information, then?

Comment: This API is only to get user details, not to edit/post user details. Customer is created with user's mobile number instantly as soon as user shows interest to some other user.

Comment: @EricStein: I have edited the question now, this should be simpler. Please check if its clear.